# Creating a SharePoint Wiki Page via JavaScript and REST or CSOM

Tags: javascript, rest, wiki, client-object-model

I'm fairly new to developing SharePoint 2013 Apps, and I was tasked to customize the Create New Wiki Page for a Site. The user has to type in the Title, I do some processing, and then when everything is OK I create a new Wiki Page entry with the specified title.

What I have is the following code, which returns a `Bad Request` error:

```
executor.executeAsync(
    {
        url: appweburl + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/doki/Wicky')/Files" +
               "/AddTemplateFile(urlOfFile='" + filename + "',templateFileType=1)",
           method: "POST",
           headers: {
               "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
               "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
               "X-RequestDigest" : $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
           },
           success: function (data) { alert('OK'); },
           error: function (data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
               alert('LOL FAIL ' + errorMessage);
           }
    }
    );
```

I have the basic List CRUD using JavaScript and CSOM but it does not work on a Wiki Library. How can I create a new Wiki page entry with a specified title using JavaScript and either CSOM or REST? (whichever works better)

Comment: Does your URL of the file include the full url to its target location? ie /wiki/page.aspx?

Answer (score 5):

You did not mention what kind of error occured, but most probably it is related with  `filename` parameter. `AddTemplateFile` endpoint accepts  *relative file Url* for `urlOfFile` parameter.

### How to create a Wiki page via SharePoint REST API

The following example demonstrates how to create Wiki page via SharePoint REST API. 
Since `AddTemplateFile` endpoint accepts  *relative file Url* for `urlOfFile` parameter, the helper function `getListUrl` is used to resolve List Url by its title

```
function createWikiPage(webUrl,listTitle,fileName,success, failure)
{

  getListUrl(webUrl,listTitle,
    function(listUrl){  

     var fileUrl = listUrl + '/' + fileName
     var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + listUrl + "')/Files" +
               "/AddTemplateFile(urlOfFile='" + fileUrl + "',templateFileType=1)";
     $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
               "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
               "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
               "X-RequestDigest" : $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data.d);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
     });

    },
    failure
  );


}


function getListUrl(webUrl,listTitle,success, failure)
{
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listTitle +  "')/RootFolder"; 
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
               "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
               "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data.d.ServerRelativeUrl);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}


//Usage
createWikiPage(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'Pages','WikiTestPage.aspx',
  function(page){  
    console.log(JSON.stringify(page));
  },
  function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
);
```

> Note: The request executor is not utilized in this example since it is
>   assumed that site URL is in the same domain as the app,but if needed
>   it could be transformed using request executor.

Answer (score 1):

Try to encode every Strings value you are sending to the WebApp using **encodeURIComponent()** function, as SharePoint is very sensitive on the special characters passed in URL.

Basically, this function replace special chars like ':', '/' or ' ' by it's corresponding hexadecimal value. For instance, the whitespace char will be replaced by "%20" value.