# Create a Sharepoint wiki page using JSOM

Tags: client-object-model, wiki-pages

I need to create a Sharepoint wiki page using JSOM, Can anyone guide me to create path?
I'm very very new to Sharepoint and eager to learn.

I found this but it uses Rest API and didn't find it very useful to me
[Creating a SharePoint Wiki Page via JavaScript and REST or CSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/78669/creating-a-sharepoint-wiki-page-via-javascript-and-rest-or-csom)

Answer (score 1):

### How to create enterprise wiki page using SharePoint 2013 JSOM

```
function createEntWikiPage(pageName,pageContent,success,error)
{
    var templateRedirectionPageMarkup = "<%@ Page Inherits=\"Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c\" %> <%@ Reference VirtualPath=\"~TemplatePageUrl\" %> <%@ Reference VirtualPath=\"~masterurl/custom.master\" %>";
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var wikiPages = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Pages");
    var fileInfo = new SP.FileCreationInformation();
    fileInfo.set_url(pageName);
    var fileContent = new SP.Base64EncodedByteArray();
    for (var i = 0; i < templateRedirectionPageMarkup.length; i++) {

        fileContent.append(templateRedirectionPageMarkup.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    fileInfo.set_content(fileContent);
    fileInfo.set_overwrite(true);

    var wikiFile = wikiPages.get_rootFolder().get_files().add(fileInfo);
    var wikiPage = wikiFile.get_listItemAllFields();
    wikiPage.set_item("PublishingPageContent",pageContent);
    var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl == '/' ? _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl : _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + '/';
    wikiPage.set_item("PublishingPageLayout",siteUrl + "_catalogs/masterpage/EnterpriseWiki.aspx, Basic Page");
    wikiPage.update();
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
      function() {
         success(wikiFile);
      },
      error);
}
```

Usage

```
createEntWikiPage(
   'Greetings.aspx',
   '<h2>Welcome to SharePoint!</h2>',
   function(file){
      console.log(String.format('Enterprise wiki page {0} has been created',file.get_name()));
   },
   function(sender,args){
      console.log(args.get_message());
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach on MSDN seems to be using the REST API.
Nonetheless, the `SPFolder.Files.addTemplateFile` method seems to be available through CSOM/JSOM, for which it seems possible to use that approach as well.

This [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246890(v=office.15).aspx) reference shows the available method

This [reference](http://spdevlab.com/2013/03/28/creating-wiki-web-part-and-publishing-pages-via-csom-in-sharepoint-2010/) shows the approach on CSOM (managed code). Adapting that to use JSOM looks fairly possible.

And finally this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841(v=office.15).aspx#bk_FileCollectionAddTemplateFile) reference explains the REST approach for using `addTemplateFile`

Hopefully a combination of those 3 well explained posts will put you on the right track to achieve what's required.