# SP2013: JavaScript Object Model - Setting the value of a list field

Tags: 2013, list, javascript, client-object-model, publishing-page

How do I set the value of a field in a list using the JavaScript object model? I am trying to click a button on an existing page that automatically creates a new wikipage (which I have done) and populate it with content like "Hello!"

I know I need to set the field 'publishingPageContent', but I'm having trouble setting it. Thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how to update enterprise wiki page content:

```
function updateWikiPage(pageUrl,pageContent,success,error)
{
  getFileWithProperties(pageUrl,
  function(file){
     var listItem = file.get_listItemAllFields(); 
     var itemProperties = {'PublishingPageContent': pageContent};
     updateListItem(listItem,itemProperties,success,error);
  },
  error);
}
```

where

```
function getFileWithProperties(url,success,error) {

   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
   var file = ctx.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(url);   
   ctx.load(file,'ListItemAllFields'); 

   ctx.executeQueryAsync(
      function () {
         success(file);
      }, 
      error);
}


function updateListItem(listItem,properties,success,error) 
{
   var ctx = listItem.get_context();
   for(var propName in properties) {
       listItem.set_item(propName, properties[propName]) 
   }
   listItem.update();
   ctx.executeQueryAsync(
       function () {
         success();
       }, 
       error);
}
```

Usage

```
updateWikiPage('/kb/Pages/Home.aspx','<b>Welcome to SharePoint</b>',
  function(){
     console.log('Wiki page has been updated succesfully');
  }, 
  function(sender,args){
     console.log(args.get_message());
  });
```

Comment: For anyone who needs help with the initial part of creating the wiki page using the JavaScript object model, @VadimGremyachev posted an answer that I used as well. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/78669/creating-a-sharepoint-wiki-page-via-javascript-and-rest-or-csom